# wireless connections cannot interact with wired connections

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a wireless router (buffalo airstation) and several boxes connected to it by wire.
I can ssh between them, e.g.:

```
box1$ ssh box2
box2$
```

if, however, `box1` is connected wirelessly, `ssh box2` fails with `No route to host`.
(`ssh`, `wget`, `firefox` &c to the internet work fine with both wireless and wired connections). `ping box2` fails with `Destination Host Unreachable`. (name `box2` is resolved to the correct IP address by both `ping` and `ssh`, probably because they are specified in /etc/hosts).

when `box1` is connected by wire `ifconfig` prints:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:f5:80:d8:dc  
          inet addr:192.168.7.101  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::290:f5ff:fe80:d8dc/64 Scope:Link
```

wireless:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:5c:46:e6:a5  
          inet addr:192.168.7.103  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:5cff:fe46:e6a5/64 Scope:Link
```

note that this is for the *client* `box1` which initiates the connection; the *server* `box2` which is `ping`ed is always wired:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:ba:c8:0d:c7
          inet addr:192.168.7.100  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:baff:fec8:dc7/64 Scope:Link
```

Again, note that both wired and wireless connections work perfectly when accessing the internet behind the the router.

So, how come I cannot connect to the wired `box2` from wireless box `box1`?

Comment: Can you post a ```netstat -rn``` from box when connected by wireless?

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings on your router, look in the wireless setup, or advanced wireless setup, look for an option possibly named "WLAN Partitioning". (my DIR-655 has this) It prevents wireless systems from seeing or contacting any other computers on the router.  So wired machines see each other, but wireless machines are 'partitioned' off and prevented from talking except to internet.

Comment: on my buffalo airstation I unchecked the box "Separate feature" under "wireless config"/"basic" and it works now!